# Docstring for batch_norm() does not match latest code in tensorflow.contrib.layers

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use the latest batch_norm() and found it here: [batch_norm](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py). If I use `help(tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm)` from IPython, I see the following docstring of interest:

> Note: When is_training is True the moving_mean and moving_variance
>   need to be
>       updated, by default the update_ops are placed in `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` so they need to be added as a dependency to
>   the `train_op`, example:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
if update_ops:
    updates = tf.group(*update_ops)
    total_loss = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([updates], total_loss)
```

However the source code at [batch_norm](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py) has the following docstring which has been corrected.

> Note: When is_training is True the moving_mean and moving_variance
>   need to be   updated, by default the update_ops are placed in
>   `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` so   they need to be added as a dependency
>   to the `train_op`, example:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
  train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Using `tf.__version__` from IPython prompt, I get '0.12.1'. How can I tell if the code I am running is the same as the latest in tf.contrib.layers? If only the docstring changed and the code is the same, I would rather not upgrade or reinstall tensorflow as I have everything working well with GPU. My install is inside of a mini conda environment and tensorflow was originally installed with pip from inside this environment. Also, if I do need a different version, what is the best way to get it and then test that I have the matching version from tf.contrib.layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to verify that I did not have the latest code by doing a diff on the file of interest with my local copy. I did this by first downloading the file `layers.py` from Github at [layers.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py). I clicked on the raw button and then saved the image to a local directory. In my case the local copy was located in my miniconda directory under `site-packages`. At that point it was apparent that my version of tensorflow needed to be updated so I installed the latest version. This install broke an existing miniconda environment however which was unexpected. See [installing tensorflow...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879119/installing-tensorflow-in-cloned-conda-enviroment-breaks-conda-enviroment-it-was)