# Installing tensorflow in cloned conda environment breaks conda environment it was cloned from

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pip, miniconda

I just cloned a working miniconda environment `carnd-term1-gpu` that had tensorflow with gpu working using tensorflow version '0.12.1'. The environment had a lot of other python packages installed. I wanted to upgrade to the latest version of tensorflow so I did the following based on [tensorflow Ubuntu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux):

1) cloned the existing working environment as `tflow`

```
conda create --name tflow --clone carnd-term1-gpu
```

This completed successfully.

2) source activate tflow and install using pip

```
source activate tflow
(tflow) xx@pc:~$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Now I try to run the old environment assuming that it should not be changed.

```
source activate carnd-term1-gpu
ipython
```

Then from ipython prompt type `import numpy as np` and get following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4ee716103900> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np

/home/ai/miniconda3/envs/carnd-term1-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    140         return loader(*packages, **options)
    141 
--> 142     from . import add_newdocs
    143     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    144                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

/home/ai/miniconda3/envs/carnd-term1-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

/home/ai/miniconda3/envs/carnd-term1-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from numpy.version import version as __version__
      7 
----> 8 from .type_check import *
      9 from .index_tricks import *
     10 from .function_base import *

/home/ai/miniconda3/envs/carnd-term1-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py in <module>()
      9            'common_type']
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, \
     13                 obj2sctype, zeros

/home/ai/miniconda3/envs/carnd-term1-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py in <module>()
     51 from . import shape_base
     52 from .shape_base import *
---> 53 from . import einsumfunc
     54 from .einsumfunc import *
     55 del nt

ImportError: cannot import name 'einsumfunc'
```

I thought I was protected by cloning a separate environment and only changing that environment, however it seems that the install in one environment changed behavior in the other environment. Exactly what I thought I was avoiding! What went wrong and how do I fix this? The new environment seems to work fine so far.

I  checked the file dates in both environments. The `carnd-term1-gpu` environment had files that were dated the same day that I did the upgrade in the `tflow` environment. Any ideas on how that could happen?

I tried adding the missing file `einsumfunc.py` to my `carnd-term1-gpu` environment and started Ipython again. This time when I did `import numpy as np` a different file could not be imported. So it looks like my `carnd-term1-gpu` environment is corrupted.

Comparing `conda list` for each environment and looking only at `numpy`, I see the following:
For `tflow`  environment:

```
numpy                     1.11.3                    <pip>
numpy                     1.12.1                    <pip>
numpy                     1.11.3          py35_blas_openblas_200  [blas_openblas]  conda-forge
```

And for `carnd-term1-gpu` environment:

```
numpy                     1.11.3                    <pip>
numpy                     1.11.3          py35_blas_openblas_200  [blas_openblas]  conda-forge
```

I then looked at revisions using `conda list --revisions`. Both environments only show a single revision of `rev 0`. Likewise looking at `conda-meta/history` only shows the original creation dates of Jan. 13th for `carnd-term1-gpu` and May 9 for `tflow`. So the combination of this version of pip:

```
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
```

combined with this wheel:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

somehow corrupted the environment `carnd-term1-gpu`. This seems like either a bug or I somehow got a corrupted wheel from the tensorflow site? If it is the later, how could it corrupt a different environment than the one installed from? 
Note version of pip was same in both environments.

I did the following to investigate what files changed on the date that I did the install.

```
find /home/ai/miniconda3/envs/carnd-term1-gpu/  -type f -newermt 2017-05-09 -ls | wc -l
```

This showed 669 files were created/modified. Most of these were in `/site-packages/numpy/`, but `six.py`, `pyparsing.py`,`/setuptools/`,`/pkg_resources/`,`easy_install.py`,`/werkzeug/` were also affected.

`conda --version` is 4.2.12

I tried the following to get my old environment going again.

```
conda env export > environment.yml
conda env create -f environment.yml -n sdc-gpu
```

This resulted in following errors:

```
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ai/miniconda3/envs/sdc-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/home/ai/miniconda3/envs/sdc-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/home/ai/miniconda3/envs/sdc-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/home/ai/miniconda3/envs/sdc-gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named 'packaging'

CondaValueError: Value error: pip returned an error.
```

Comment: Which version of conda is this? Share output for `conda --version`

Comment: I added conda version at end of post. 4.2.12

Comment: Could you please try updating the conda version to 4.3.17 and see if the issue persists? `conda update conda`

Comment: Should I do this from outside any environments or within environment?

Comment: What will this do? I am a little concerned as I have 5 months of work under the previous environment that is now broken and will not run my existing code. The new environment appears to be working. If this change breaks that one, is it reversible?

Comment: Can you try to use `conda env export` to export the old env in a yaml file and then recreate it with `conda env create -f env.yml`? Maybe it should works

Comment: One can also install miniconda to a different location and then point it to the save package cache to save bandwidth, update conda, and try out the experiment

Comment: I don't understand @NehalJWani last comment. Please give me some more detail on how to do this experiment. What is 'point it to the save package cache' ? What is the experiment?  Seems like I am just reinstalling everything.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'same' and not 'save'. You can share the package cache using the config parameter pkgs_dirs . Setup miniconda to a different location, point it to the package cache as the old installation and then update conda and recreate your environment. Then clone it to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Do I install the latest version of miniconda (that would be python 3.6 and my old env is python 3.5), I could run `bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh` since I still have the one used for original install. But I am not sure if that will not just overwrite my existing environment. Will it give me option to change default directory?

Comment: It seems like you got your answer on the mailing list. Mind updating the answer with the `--copy` flag?

Comment: Could someone upvote my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the following from [continuum](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/z9sor6HyWkI);
"To keep this from happening, you'll have to use the `--copy` flag with your clone operation.  Core to conda's design is extensive use of hard links.  This exact issue is one of the biggest pitfalls."

So if I would have done the following when I first cloned the environment, I could have avoided corrupting the old one:

`conda create --name tflow  --copy --clone carnd-term1-gpu`

The option  `--copy Install all packages using copies instead of hard- or soft-link‐ing` will prevent pip from being able to overwrite files.

Some ongoing discussion about this and how it might get addressed in the future is here: [conda pip breaks](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/conda/z9sor6HyWkI/PdVT7x8TAwAJ)

The only option I have for recovering is to reinstall each damaged package. Beware when using pip with conda...